# Latest ubuntu version/upgrade with 64 bit

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit

just looking to know what the latest downloadable version/upgrade of ubuntu will provide 64 bit support.  Asus g51j series, i7 core.  currenlt with ubuntu 10.10.  tried to upgrade to 11.04 back in jan 12, didnt work figure due to the 32 bit download.

Answer (score 0):

If you currently have 32bit installed the upgrade path will be to 32bit.

If you have 32bit and want 64bit - reinstall.

There was 64bit available as a download in Jan 2012. There is now - you just have to specifically change the download - 32bit is just the recommended download.

Comment: currently on 64 bit.  The asus died when i went for the 11.04 install.  must have just missed the 64 bit file.  Thanks.